# I need help loading TensorBoard on Mac

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorboard

This is currently the part that would have anything to do with logging

```
import tflearn 
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d 
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected 
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression 

import tensorflow as tf 
tf.reset_default_graph() 

convnet = input_data(shape =[None, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1], name ='input')
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation ='relu') 
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5) 
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation ='relu') 
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5) 

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 5, activation ='relu') 
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5) 

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 5, activation ='relu') 
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5) 

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 32, 5, activation ='relu') 
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 5) 

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation ='relu') 
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8) 

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, PATH_TO_NUMBER_OF_CLASSES,       activation ='softmax') 
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer ='adam', learning_rate = 0.001, 
  loss ='categorical_crossentropy', name ='targets') 

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet,tensorboard_dir = 'log')


#Seperating the image and its label(One Hot Encoder)
#X is the image
#Y is the One Hot
#Therefore, i[0] is the pixel data and i[1] is the label
X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]

model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=3, validation_set=.    ({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id='test')
```

In terminal, I make sure I'm in the tensorflow environment. Then I enter tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/log

Afterwards I copy and paste the given url in the browser and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the verbose level and equal the log directories:

```
model = DNN(optimizer, tensorboard_verbose=3, tensorboard_dir='/tmp/tflearn_logs/')
```

By the way `/tmp/tflearn_logs/` is the default of `tensorboard_dir`, so you don't have to change this parameter.

Then you can open the board with:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir='/tmp/tflearn_logs'
```

Source: http://tflearn.org/getting_started/#visualization